# Send object as json to Sentry.io

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.1, sentry

We're using Sentry.AspNetCore NuGet package on our web site and we are injecting `ILogger<T>`s here and there.
Is there any way to use "structured logging syntax" and make Sentry log objects as JSON instead of just calling `ToString()`?

```
_logger.LogError("testObj = {@testObj}", new TestClass());
// (The @ forces NLog to serialize object as JSON. Looks like it's used in some of the other logging frameworks as well.)

public class TestClass
{
    public string SomeProp { get; } = "SomeValue";
    public int AnotherProp { get; } = 1337;
}

// Preferred message: testObj = {"SomeProp":"SomeValue","AnotherProp":1337}
// Actual Message: testObj = MyNameSpace.TestClass
```

EDIT:
Some clarification. We still use NLog to write to file and we just added `UseSentry` in `Program.cs` and kept all our `ILogger<T>` usages as is. It works as expected apart from the fact that Sentry(?) only uses `ToString` to serialize objects passed to the message string.
A solution to our problem could be to somehow inject a custom formatter into the Sentry logger. Otherwise we will have to override `ToString` on every class that we might want to log, or add serialization ourselves or create anonymous objects when logging.

(Logging of anonymous objects "works" since the compiler generates a custom `.ToString()` override that lists all properties and their stringified values.
Example:  https://sharplab.io/#v2:EYLgxg9gTgpgtADwGwBYA+ABATARgLABQGAzAATakDCpA3oaQ+WRiqQLIAUAlLfY/wDcAhlFIJSAXlIA7GAHdapACowAzgBdJpAETq167aQC+Abj4MjhI0A= )

Answer (score 0):

Even though I see [`@` is in NLog's docs](https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/How-to-use-structured-logging#formatting-of-the-message), try to remove the `@` from your string format:

Instead of `_logger.LogError("testObj = {@testObj}", new TestClass());`

Write: `_logger.LogError("testObj = {testObj}", new TestClass());`

I'm suspecting it might be a NLog backing changing the formatter?

If I run [this sample of Sentry.Extensions.Logging](https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/42b0f921f0503c561046b96c3ad486511487e7cb/samples/Sentry.Samples.ME.Logging/Program.cs), without NLog, adding:

```cs
logger.LogCritical("{number} - An event with a complex object: {object}", 1, new
{
    Name = "Zealot",
    Health = "100%",
});
```

I see in Sentry:

`1 - An event with a complex object: { Name = Zealot, Health = 100% }`

It might be a limitation when using Sentry.NLog.

Comment: Actually the NLog example also works; https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/blob/42b0f921f0503c561046b96c3ad486511487e7cb/samples/Sentry.Samples.NLog/Program.cs#L63-L71

Comment: Yes, anonymous objects serialize as "expected", but not when you have a typed class.
Anonymous classes seem to have a ToString override that looks almost as JSON.
Perhaps there is a way to override the formatter?

Comment: That sounds like a bug then. Would you mind raising one on GitHub? https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/new

Comment: I don't think it is a bug per se, more likely a feature request. Perhaps it could work the same way as NLog (and others), in that an @ before the parameter name tells the formatter to serialize the parameter as JSON instead of using ToString.

Comment: For future reference, here is the issue on github: https://github.com/getsentry/sentry-dotnet/issues/556